# sharepoint online calendar does not save events

Tags: sharepoint-online

I created a subsite in sharepoint online and was able to pull calendar into it, but it does not save events: after I open "create new event" dialogue, fill it out and hit "Save" - the calendar is not saving it. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Which site template in your subsite?

Try to create a new sub site and create a calendar list to check it it works.

Using IE/Chrome F12 to check if some JS errors occurs.

And check if have some custom code in the calendar NewForm.aspx page.

Or provide more details about how to reproduce this issue, others would get easier to research on it.

Comment: I am using "Team Site" template. -> then "Site Contents"-> "New"->"App"-> select "Calendar" app->then give it a name. It now shows as event list in Site Contents. then I tried to add events there - did not save. Also I tried creating a new page and adding the calendar to the page using "Insert" tab->"App part" button. Same result.

Comment: Did you see some js errors using IE F12?

Comment: could you please tell me at what step of the above I need to press F12?

Comment: Check article: https://dzone.com/articles/debug-javascript-in-internet-explorer-11-in-7-easy

Comment: Actually sorry, my mistake. I found out today that the events were actually saved. In the "Calendar" tab I changed the view from "calendar" to "All events" view and they all showed up. How do I make them show in the   "calendar"  view?

Comment: Nevermind. I found the answer: Set "Group calendar" to NO

Comment: Glad to hear that you solve this issue, thanks for your sharing.

Comment: you are welcome